# Laravel 5.6 sent email

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.6

I am trying to sent an email using laravel 5.6 but I fail.

In my .env file I put my private gmail, so that all mails are sent to this email.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Further I created a Mailable class like this:

```
class InquirySent extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->data['email'])
                    ->view('emails.contacts.inquiry');
    }
}
```

I just Need to add this data to the mail which I get from a form:

```
array:3 [
  "name" => "foo"
  "email" => "test@gmail.com"
  "phoneNumber" => "16547613247805"
]
```

In my Controller I have following function to sent the mail:

```
public function sent(ContactRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    Mail::to(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))->send(new InquirySent($data));
}
```

The error message:

```
{,…}
exception
:
"ErrorException"
file
:
"D:\laragon\www\tim\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php"
line
:
94
message
:
"stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:↵error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"
trace
:
[{function: "handleError", class: "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions", type: "->"},…]
```

Comment: and where's error message?

Comment: @devnullΨ sorry updated the question

Comment: Can you try port 465 ?

Comment: @Chris using port 465 gives me no error but I do not get an email aswell ?

Comment: did you allow less secure app in your gmail? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @devnullΨ allowed it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

In config folder find mail.php file and ADD BELOW CODE.

```
'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
```

Comment: there is no ssl Keyword in that file

Comment: @tigerel i have modified my answer please look it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. Add some delay and try to use queue. Also tls could be a problem. You can delete it or block ssl permissions.

```
 Mail::to(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))->send((new InquirySent($data))->delay(30));
```

and `php artisan queue:work`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to  [@Cool's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49611923/6511325), for **Laravel 5.6** you need to ADD this code to *config/mail.php*

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
]
```